On Heine-Borel Theorem for any compact set.
I have recently studied the Heine-Borel theorem i.e. set is compact iff any open cover has a finite subcover. I have proven it only for compact intervals and their cartesian products for higher dimensions. I was told it follows directly and that it applies to any compact set. In particular, the sets $X \subset \mathbb R^n$ (Definition of compact is closed and bounded)
My question is how could one show this? Thank you for any ideas or insights.

Well, what's your definition of compact? Closed and bounded? Every sequence has a convergent subsequence?

@Mousedorff Good catch. I made an edit, it is closed and bounded.

Closed and bounded only applies in Euclidean space. The general statement is that open cover compact is equivalent to totally bounded and complete is equivalent to sub sequential compactness

@person It's obvious that the author of the question is concerned with Euclidean space from the way they asked the question (compact intervals, cartesian products for higher dimensions).

@user469053 Indeed true. Fixed.


is true in any Hausdorff space, but for your purposes you only need it for Euclidean space. Similarly for 2. with metric spaces.


@user469053 Thanks for the ideas!

Here would be my outline (wording fixed): Say a set is $C$-compact if every open cover has a finite subcover. 1. Show that every $C$-compact set in a Hausdorff space is closed. 2. Any $C$-compact set in a metric space is bounded. 3. Every closed subset of a $C$-compact set is $C$-compact. Corollary: Any $C$ compact subset in Euclidean space is a closed subset of a product of closed, finite intervals (which you already showed are $C$-compact). This shows that $C$-compact implies closed and bounded. Items 1 and 2 give the converse.

I fixed my previous comment, which was worded as if the definition of compact that you're using is "every open cover has a finite subcover." But you've stated that that's not the definition that you're using, so I shouldn't have said "compact" when I meant "every open cover has a finite subcover."

I guess you consider subsetsm $X \subset \mathbb R^n$. If so, edit your question to include this essential information.

I agree with @PaulFrost ... If you do not say "subset of $\mathbb R^n$" in the question, you will continue to get lots of counterexamples for other cases.

@PaulFrost Thank you, fixed it. There are quite a few things I missed out on in the formulation of the question since I am not very familiar with metrics. I have not taken topology yet. I apologise.

I will shorten "any open cover of $A$ has a finite subcover" to "$A$ is cover-compact". Given what you know already, it suffices to prove that cover-compact subsets are compact and closed subsets of cover-compact sets are cover-compact, since any bounded set is a subset of a product of rectangles. Let us check each of these.

Cover-compact sets are bounded: If $A$ is cover-compact then its open cover $\{B(0, r) \mid r > 0\}$ has a finite subcover, which implies that $A \subset B(0, r)$ for some $r$.
Cover-compact sets are closed: Suppose $A$ is cover-compact and $x \notin A$ is a limit point. Since $x \notin A$, we have an open cover $\{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \overline{B}(x, r) \mid r > 0\}$ by complements of closed balls around $x$. But the union of a finite subcollection given by radii $r_1 < \dots < r_k$ is just $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \overline{B}(x, r_1)$. Since $x$ is a limit point of $A$, the ball $B(x, r_1)$ contains some point of $A$ and hence the above finite union cannot cover $A$.
Closed subsets of cover-compact sets are cover-compact: Let $A$ be cover-compact and $F \subset A$ be closed. Now for any open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $F$, $\mathcal{U} \cup \{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus F\}$ is an open cover of $A$, therefore has a finite subcover $\mathcal{U}_A$. Then $\mathcal{U}_A \cap \mathcal{U}$ is a finite cover of $F$ and a subset of $\mathcal{U}$.


Great answer but I am a little confused about the second point, could you clarify how you reached such a conclusion? Maybe I'm not seeing something obvious

@TeodorasPaura added details to the second point.

Thanks, I think I get it now. :)

Not every closed and bounded set is compact. For example consider $X=\mathbb{N}$ with the metric $d(n,m)=1$ for $n\neq m.$ The metric space $X$ is bounded and complete. Every point $n$ is an open subset of $X$ and $X=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{n\}.$ However there is no finite subcover.

Since $d(n,n)=1$, I'd say $d$ is not a metric. Not really a problem though, since it's enough to let $d(n,m)=0$ iff $n=m$ by definition and $d(n,m)=1$ otherwise.

@NtLake Thanks. Corrected

The question isn't clear. First things first, this is the topological definition of compact set:
Definition. A set $X$ is said to be compact if and only if every open cover of $X$ has a finite subcover.
Now, the Heine-Borel theorem states that $X \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded. It's wrong to say that a set that is closed and bounded is necessarily compact in general.
